# Python altered variable when used in requests

Tags: python

it'a strange error (i'm new to python), I hope I can explain it.
I need update a swarm stack with a REST call and use `requests`. I have a yaml file that I convert to a string and put into body of request.

yaml file:

```
version: '3'
networks:
 ycf:
  driver: overlay
services:
 api:
  image: registry.gitlab.com/ycf/api/api:latest
  restart: always
  environment:
   - MONGODB_DB_URL=mongodb://mongodb:27017
   - MONGODB_USER=ycf
   - MONGODB_PSW=xxxx
   - AUTH_KEY=wrv9ghefiu
   - PASSWORD_KEY=xxxx
   - PORT=3000
  working_dir: /opt/api
  command: ./node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js prod
  networks:
   ycf:
  links:
   - mongodb
 app:
  image: registry.gitlab.com/ycf/app/app:latest
  restart: always
  networks:
   ycf:
```

After conversion i have:

```
version: '3'\r\nnetworks:\r\n ycf:\r\n  driver: overlay\r\nservices:\r\n api:\r\n  image: registry.gitlab.com\/ycf\/api\/api:latest\r\n  restart: always\r\n  environment:\r\n   - MONGODB_DB_URL=mongodb:\/\/mongodb:27017\r\n   - MONGODB_USER=ycf\r\n   - MONGODB_PSW=xxxx\r\n   - AUTH_KEY=wrv9ghefiu\r\n   - PASSWORD_KEY=xxxx\r\n   - PORT=3000\r\n  working_dir: \/opt\/api\r\n  command: .\/node_modules\/yarn\/bin\/yarn.js prod\r\n  networks:\r\n   ycf:\r\n  links:\r\n   - mongodb\r\n app:\r\n  image: registry.gitlab.com\/ycf\/app\/app:latest\r\n  restart: always\r\n  networks:\r\n   ycf:\r\n
```

I make this steps:

```
# Convert swarm-stack.yml to string and assign the result to "compose" variable
run = subprocess.run(['./jsonstring.py', 'swarm-stack.yml'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
compose = run.stdout.decode('utf-8')
print(compose) # this result is identical to the string written above 
url_update = 'http://www.example.com:9000/api/endpoints/1/stacks/id'
# Then use variable "compose" to build the body of requests
body_update = {'StackFileContent' :'%s'%(compose)}
```

`body_update` now is:

```
{'StackFileContent': "version: '3'\\r\\nnetworks:\\r\\n ycf:\\r\\n  driver: overlay\\r\\nservices:\\r\\n api:\\r\\n  image: registry.gitlab.com\\/ycf\\/api\\/api:latest\\r\\n  restart: always\\r\\n  environment:\\r\\n   - MONGODB_DB_URL=mongodb:\\/\\/mongodb:27017\\r\\n   - MONGODB_USER=ycf\\r\\n   - MONGODB_PSW=xxxx\\r\\n   - AUTH_KEY=wrv9ghefiu\\r\\n   - PASSWORD_KEY=xxxx\\r\\n   - PORT=3000\\r\\n  working_dir: \\/opt\\/api\\r\\n  command: .\\/node_modules\\/yarn\\/bin\\/yarn.js prod\\r\\n  networks:\\r\\n   ycf:\\r\\n  links:\\r\\n   - mongodb\\r\\n app:\\r\\n  image: registry.gitlab.com\\/ycf\\/app\\/app:latest\\r\\n  restart: always\\r\\n  networks:\\r\\n   ycf:\\r\\n\n"}
```

backslashes are added to existing ones, and \n is added at the end of the string, this cause a 500 error. I use python 3.5.2, any idea?

Thanks

Comment: a slash in python means it is escaping a character.. `\n` = newline, `\t` = tab and special characters such as `\` `"`, `'` have to  be escaped.. you need to unescape if you wish to uninclude them..

Comment: what does `json_string.py` look like.. there should be more \ in the string for `'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe you can try a different decode option.

In this instance `unicode_escape` may help..

```
compose = run.stdout.decode('unicode_escape')
```